# How do Area Glow and Revealing Light work differently when revealing invisible creatures?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, invisibility, spheres-of-power

When using the magic system Spheres of Power, the sphere of Light can cause a creature or object to glow. This effect negates all the bonuses given by invisibility. If you augment it with Area Glow, you cause all creatures and objects within a small range (10 ft. + 5 ft. every 5 caster levels) to glow, thereby negating all their invisibility bonuses.

On the other hand, Revealing Light creates a bright light that is bigger (35 ft. + 5 ft. every 2 caster levels) and reveals all invisible creatures and objects.

My question is, other than the fact that Revealing Light has a much bigger area of effect, is there any difference between the two talents with regards to revealing invisible creatures and objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Glow follows the affected creature.

When you spend a Spell Point to Area Glow, all creatures within 10+5/5CL ft. of your target (usually yourself or a touch attack) are affected. They remain Glow'd 1 minute per caster level, regardless of where they go.

This is analogous to [Faerie Fire](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/faerie-fire/).

### Revealing Light radiates from the target of a Glow.

You could cast Glow on yourself or another target and by spending a Spell Point you make it a Revealing Light. However, only targets within range of *you or your touched target* would be revealed (at the end of each of *your* turns). The range for this is the same as the Glow affect (10+5/CL ft.) unless you Concentrate on the effect as a Standard Action or have spent a second Spell Point to increase it to 30+5/2CL ft.

This is more like [Invisibility Purge](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/invisibility-purge/).

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, with Revealing Light, a revealed invisible creature that moved during its turn, would become invisible again until the end of my next turn, whereas with Area Glow it would remain glowing and, therefore, seeable, right?

Comment: That sounds accurate. To clarify, if I were GM, I'd rule they have to move *out* of the Revealing Light to regain invisibility, not just move within the range.